# A different artificial gravity: Ultradense material

Tags: technology, hard-science, gravity, spaceships

Guests of this large space station enjoy Earth-like gravity (80-90% minimum).

How? Well the space station is so massive it has its own gravity. The disk shaped "core" is made with ultradense materials with an overall of 20-30 g/cm3 similar to Iridium or Osmium (the densest elements).

I thought that working with material with such density could provide decent gravity with relatively little amount of material so I tried crunching some numbers...

Turns out I suck at math. How massive/large does a disk with these density have to be to provide similar gravitational pull close to its surface?
(Ignore edge effects and the core does not have to keep its own atmosphere, even if you can just provide some formulas it would be great since right now I don't have much time for this)

Comment: Just some questions, do the astronauts evolve directly on the surface of the disc ? Are they far away ? do they walk on the side of the disk ? Furthermore a real disc needs a height because we are in a 3D world, what height (thickness) do you want for your disc ?

Comment: @EngelOfChipolata Evolve? The astronauts are just astronauts, they came and go on spaceships, maybe some have very long shifts but mostly don't complete a biological cycle on the station. They do however "stand" on the two surfaces of the disk. The thickness can be whichever is enough to generate enough pull.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, by "evolve" I meant "moving, dancing, living, sleeping" not the Darwin kind of things :S. So to be clear your astronauts are "walking" "on" and "under" the disc right ? And you have to be conscious that your disc needs to be a cylinder (even with a really little height) to exists, even a sheet of paper has a thickness. So I can set the thickness to 1m, only the radius of the cylinder will be calculated. Are you okay ? (I will probably just post the result with not many explanation but tomorrow I will ad more and you will set the values that you want)

Comment: @EngelOfChipolata ahahaha yes the do everything "onto" the disk (sorry I'm a biologist). I don't care about the thickness if it doesn't influence the surface gravity though I guess at least for structural reason it's best if it is at least  a few meters.

Comment: Yes it influence the gravity a lot, because what matters is the mass of your cylinder, the more height the less it needs to be large.

Comment: Give it the thickness you want! I want the "faces" to be at least 300m in diameter

Comment: You will have them, at least millions times more

Comment: You really need neutronium or something similar for this to be "practical".

Comment: 300m in diameter? That's not nearly big enough to create gravity. Even a cube at that size would be negilgible in the gravitic sense.

Comment: Osmium etc. are ordinary elements. When SF refers to ultradense materials  it normally means something much denser than ordinary matter.  Robert L. Forward wrote about this use in a couple shorts illustrating the idea, to be found in [*Indistinguishable from Magic*](http://www.baen.com/chapters/W200602/0671876864.htm).

Comment: I think one of the biggest problems though with having such a setup is that your space station will attract all kinds of space debris to it. To see what happens to a body (without an atmosphere) that attracts stuff to it, see the moon.

Comment: Related: https://what-if.xkcd.com/68/

Comment: Although I don't think a dense cylinder is a realistic way to build a space station, it would be fun to walk on the curved edge and then jump off, falling towards the centre of the disc, sliding over its surface past the centre and then oscillating before eventually coming to rest near the centre.

Comment: Late comment, but Nutronium would be much much denser than either Iridium or Osmium. You could have a much more compact core.

Answer (score 8):

A disk won't really work in the sense that you want it to. Supposing that your material was massive enough to create an appreciable gravitic field, a body would be attracted to the centre of the disk. The centre of mass needs to be directly below your astronauts; they need to walk on the edge of the disk, not the flat dorsal or ventral surfaces.

Additionally, the increase in density is only a four-fold increase, while the decrease in volume will be exponential by going from a sphere to a disk. Logically, your prospective disk will have to be an order of magnitude larger in radius than the earth in order to achieve earth-like mass (and therefore gravitational attraction).

You need some fantastic substance to make this idea viable, either to take the associated interstellar punishment and associated integrity issues that would be dealt out to a disk sized like an enormous net spread out across a solar orbit, or to have some fantastically hyperdense material that will give you the gravity you want. In the latter case, this fantastic substance is entirely under your control, and you can handwave its required properties away.

EDIT: This doesn't even address the problem of how you would prevent your disk from collapsing in on itself. There's a reason celestial bodies are shaped roughly like spheres.

EDIT: @TLW points out that for a [sufficiently large disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alderson_disk), the gravitational field changes so that gravity can no longer be approximated by a point. Very cool, but nevertheless huge, and prone to all the problems of a system-sized megastructure.

Comment: Very roughly, at 1m thick, your iridium disk would need to be about 4.64 million kilometers in radius. By comparison, Earth is just 6,371 Km in radius. That disk will be about two-thirds the size of the sun; in other words, massive. The gravitational force of anything else in the vicinity, like a star that it orbits or a moon that orbits it, will tear it apart, never mind the constant bombardment from comets and other astronomical bodies.

Comment: " a body would be attracted to the centre of the disk" This is, perhaps surprisingly, false. The near-field of a disk is such that you'd be attracted towards the surface. It's only in the far-field that you're attracted towards the center of the disk. Relevant: http://www.tp4.rub.de/~jk/science/gravity/chapt_alderson.html

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of it, and I thought I was familiar with all the classic megastructures. Very cool. Nevertheless, it reinforces the point, in order to achieve the correct gravity, the disk would have to be on a solar system scale, and by the math presented at your link, about 100 km thick. Not feasible for a "space station", and still requires a fantastic material to accomplish.

Comment: If you had a method of stabilizing neutronium you could build it on a sane scale. Mind you, said stabilization likely doesn't exist.

Comment: Would making it ultradense in that fashion mitigate the requirement for the disk to be built to solar system scale? If I parsed that article correctly, the edge effects are proportional to the thickness of the disk, not the radius, meaning that shrinking the radius will mean that a higher proportion of the disk will be subject to edge effects. Perhaps I'm not understanding it correctly.

Comment: The increased density means that it can be much thinner. For a 100m disk made of neutronium it only needs to be something like 60nm thick to achieve 1G at 1m at the center. That's an aspect ratio of ~3*10^-10. For comparison a standard Alderson disk only has an aspect ratio of 10^-5 to 10^-6 or so. With spinning and variations in thickness or density, you can get the inner 90% of the radius or so even. The biggest limitation is actually "how much variation in gravity between your feet and your head is acceptable". 100m probably won't cut it (~20cm/s^2 difference), but larger != stellar scale.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the space station would induce nausea due to the changing distribution of the amount of gravitational force in different directions as the astronauts walk over the surface.  In the center of the disk, for example, I imagine the astronaut would not feel pulled downward as much as they would feel pulled to the edges of the disk.  Any effort to fix this likely results in a space station that is spheroid.

To simplify the math, let's set aside the disk shape idea and just think about a spheroid space station made entirely out of material at the upper end of the density range you provided, 30 g/cm3.

The earth has a mass of $5.972 * 10^{24} kg$.  $80\%$ of this is $4.778 * 10^{24} kg$, or $4.778 * 10^{27} g$ because there are $10^3 g / kg$.  To get this much mass with a $30 g / cm^3$ material, you need:

$$ \frac{4.778 * 10^{27} g}{30 g / cm^3} = \frac{4.778 * 10^{26} g}{3 g / cm^3} = \frac{1.593 * 10^{26} g}{1 g / cm^3} = 1.593 * 10^{26} cm^3$$

In a cubic meter, there are $100^3$ cubic centimeters, and in a cubic kilometer, there are $(10^3)^3$ meters or $10^9$ meters.  We end up with $1.593 * 10^{11} km^3$.  The earth is approximately 1 trillion $km^3$, so our space station, if spheroid, would be about $16\%$ the size of the earth.

Smashing that sphere into a disk does things to the gravitational field that I am not qualified to answer; I can only imagine it would be very disorienting to walk across.

Comment: Ok that is the result I expected, I give you the other method tomorrow !

Comment: Geez! That's big! Just a bit smaller than the moon!

Comment: You can mitigate the nausea effect by varying the mass distribution over the disk and/or rotating the disk slightly: http://www.tp4.rub.de/~jk/science/gravity/chapt_alderson.html

Comment: "In the center of the disk, for example, I imagine the astronaut would not feel pulled downward as much as they would feel pulled to the edges of the disk" - nope, that's not how gravity works.

Comment: By the way, if your space station is orbiting the Earth, having a structure that has the same gravitational force than the body you are orbiting around is may not a good idea. Because remember that if you are attracted by a body (the Earth), this body is also attracted by you. This would probably result in a change in the Earth orbit around the Sun and a huge amount of energy would be needed to your station to reach the orbital speed.

Comment: Sorry, but everything in this answer is wrong. As mentioned, you wouldn't feel weird on a disk (unless black-hole sized). Gravity will always pulls you toward one point. Also, as pointed in another answer, your math is wrong ; gravity decreases with the squared distance, so the same mass with half the radius will increase surface gravity four fold. For the same surface gravity with a density 5 time higher, you need 20% of earth radius (1275km), which is 0.8% of its volume and 4% of its mass.

Comment: @ElderBug The inverse square law for gravity applies to point masses, and is only an accurate approximation outside the bounding sphere of the object in question. Standing near the centre of the flat surface of a cylinder, the gravity is approximately inversely proportional to your height above the surface, for a sufficiently large radius cylinder, and sufficiently close to the surface. (Just pointing this out - I still disagree with the answer, and wouldn't expect any nausea.)

Comment: @trichoplax Well, of course the inverse square law becomes hard to calculate if the mass isn't a point. I just mentioned it because for surface gravity (the answer only do the math for a sphere), you get cube volume by inverse square distance, so it becomes linear. And yes, on the center of a disk, you wouldn't be pulled much (analog to standing at the center of earth). My point is just that if you "feel" pulled by gravity, its only toward one point, and not "to the edges".

Comment: @ElderBug Ah, I see. Yes I agree that at the centre of the disc surface the only gravity you would feel would be axially ("downwards").

Comment: @trichoplax - Actually, in the near-field the direction of gravity is to zeroth order always towards the surface. It's only when height above the surface is a significant chunk of the distance to the edge of the disk that the local gravity significantly deviates from straight "down". Remember gravity is inverse-square. At any point you can break the disk into two parts - a circle as-large-as-possible directly below you, and a crescent far away from you. The circle pulls you straight down and is very close to you, but the crescent's at least <distance between you and edge> away from you.

Comment: @TLW that's a nice way of picturing it. I mentioned the centre since that's where it doesn't need to be an approximation - down is down to any order there.

Answer (score 3):

Gravitation on the surface scales linearly with radius and density. The earth has a radius of 6,400 km and a density ~ 5g/cm3. Irridium and osmium have densities about 20g/cm3, thats 4 times earths density.

Therefore the radius of the sphere is 1/4 that of earth to produce normal gravity.
1,600km radius ball of osmium might be hard to find. If you want 80% gravity then 1,600*80%=1,300km radius.
4/3*Pi*r^3 tels us that the volume is 9.2 billion cubic km and as 1 billion cubic m is 1 cubic km and 1 cubic m weighs 20 tonnes. The volume is 9.2 billion billion m^3 and the density 20 million g/m^3. That gives a weight of 184 million billion billion gram's.

Iridium costs £10 per gram and osmium £5 per gram. (ballpark)
This makes the project cost in the region of £1 billion billion billion or £10^27.

With a world gdp of £50 thousand billion this project could be paid for in 20 thousand billion years(assuming all funds are devoted to it and osmium prices and gdp remain constant) About when the last stars are dying out.

Comment: Jup. And our galaxy is not nearly old enough so that neutron stars have cooled down to temperatures where you could mine them for some really dense material. Of course you could use the guy who tries. ;-)

Comment: Not sure the market price holds anyway for quantities that large. Is that 10^27 the FOB price for an iridium planet, or just the price for some iridium in a planet-sized vault somewhere to have my name written on it so I can collect at my own expense?

Answer (score 3):

Given a disk of radius $R$ and thickness $T$ made out of a material of density $\rho$, the gravitational acceleration a distance $h$ directly above (or below) the center of the dist is given by the integral $$\int_0^T\int_0^R\frac{2\pi\rho G}{\sqrt{x^2+(t+h)^2}}\,dx\,dt.$$ The solution is lengthy, but what really interests us is the limit as $h\to 0$, which is $$a=2\pi\rho G\left(R \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{R^2+T^2}+T}{R}\right)+T \log \left(\sqrt{R^2+T^2}+R\right)-T \log (T)\right)$$ If we assume that the thickness of the disk is very small compared to the radius of the disk, We can make some simplifications which reduce this to $$a=2\pi\rho G\left(R(1-\log 2)+R\log(R/T)\right).$$ Anyway, here are the equations you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you can stabilize neutronium, or something equally dense, this will work.

Big if, however.

Otherwise, it won't work - the density simply isn't high enough to build it on a sane scale.

Build the flooring of your station out of a sheet of neutronium ~58nm in thickness and ~100m in diameter.

A cautionary note: this will mass somewhere on the order of three-quarters of a quadrillion metric tons (~7.5 * 10<sup>14</sup> kg) - somewhere in the range of a decent asteroid (several km in radius, depending on the density of said asteroid). You had best ensure that it is safely bound to the station, lest it tear the station apart. Remember, it's 60nm thick.

Also, one had best hope that said stabilization is stable, lest it explode. That much evaporating neutronium would release on the order of 5.6*10<sup>28</sup> J of energy. (That's somewhere around the amount of energy required to stop the Moon in its orbit around the Earth, just to give you a comparison.) That's enough to melt a cm of aluminum at 45 light-seconds away (!), if I did my math correctly.

This will give you a difference in acceleration of something like 20cm/s<sup>2</sup> between head and feet, which may be annoying. Though you can mitigate this by making it larger.

In actuality, you'll want to vary the thickness depending on the radius, as well as spin it slightly (which reduces the total material required). Otherwise you'll get weird effects anywhere but the center of the disk. But with the spinning and thickness variation you can get something like 90
% of the disk's radius to be locally flat, which is good enough for most purposes.

Note that you could accomplish much the same thing with an array of small black holes - although they would have to be rather small in order to not have a noticeably "bumpy" field, and the required stabilization would be even more absurd for them than for neutronium (among other things, the Hawking radiation would mean that they would decay almost instantaneously unless stopped)

Comment: "Hawking radiation" -- wrap it in a mirror. Anything that comes out is chucked straight back in ;-) Yeah, I know, distance of mirror from event horizon, light speed, time to evaporate, can't have a static structure "on" the event horizon, check and mate.

Comment: That's a mighty strong and efficient mirror you've got there...

Comment: I just have to make sure the "mirror" is massive enough that all light paths point back down towards the original black hole. Oh hang on, I've just invented a bigger black hole. Never mind, add another mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Robert L Forward  wrote about using ultra dense materials for controlling and manipulating gravity, but when *he* was speaking of ultra dense materials the subject was the sort of degenerate material from White Dwarf stars or neutronium as you would find in a Neutron star. One example in his book "Future Magic" suggests that to nullify a 1g field you could take a 4 million ton mass and compress it to a sphere 32cm in diameter, or a disc 45cm in diameter and 10 cm thick.

Forward was always a bit playful, so some of his suggestions included supporting a disc of degenerate matter with massive diamond pillars to counteract the gravity of Earth under the disk. This would make for an amazing amusement park ride (although the ticket price would be a bit steep). Small matters like how to keep degenerate matter or neutronium from expanding at close to the speed of light outside of their environments were conveniently overlooked.

At any rate, many other posters provided the mathematical tools, so simply plug in the desired "g" field to find out what unnatural material the gravity disc will have to be made from.

Comment: Excuse me, "a 4 million mass" Tons? or what? Robert L Forward also put similar ideas in his INDISTINGUISHABLE FROM MAGIC (1995). Both books are veritable gold mines of speculation for SF writers.

Comment: Osmium is merely a dense material. Ultradense really does require densities of white dwarf matter or neutronium. This kind of ultradense matter would allow for a disc or plate of the right size for a space station. Charles Sheffield also had ultradense discs in spaceships to compensate for high-acceleration travel. Conceptually plausible, but currently practical impossibilities.

Comment: @a4android: I suppose spheres (or spinning spheroids) should still be easier than discs. With a sphere you "just" have to contain your neutron star so that the people walking about on it (well, near it) stay in the "habitable zone" where gravity is tolerable. For a disc you also have to somehow resist its very strong preference to collapse into a sphere, so you need some sort of structural support. Hand-wavium scaffold.

Comment: @SteveJessop Good idea. The notion of spinning discs flashed into my mind. But the spin rate might be relativistic. Thucydides identified that ultradense matter will rapidly collapse into spheres. Perhaps a component of exotic matter is needed to stabilize the UDM.

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually small quantities of neutronium would absurdly violently explode, not collapse. A common misconception. Neutronium is not stable at "low" pressures.

Comment: @a4android - see my previous comment

Comment: @TLW: right, I had in mind a large quantity of neutronium. A few miles is big for a space station, but not ridiculous considering the stupid-high tech levels we're talking about here. And it's about right for a neutron star. I suppose I should have said not exactly that a neutronium disc needs to be supported from collapsing, but that the process of making a neutronium disc has to be somehow supported so that it *doesn't* make a neutronium sphere which, given you're getting neutronium at all, is a much lower energy state.

Comment: Next question: what are the bounds (on radius and thickness and the relationship between the two) that determine whether a neutronium disc of specified size prefers to explode or collapse to a sphere. And what actually is the dividing line between a disc and a cylinder :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop - it is the the *minimum* surface pressure (gravitational component parallel to the local normal) that matters for "if it will explode". Your many-mile-wide disk will still explode, because the surface pressure just inside the rim is still too low.

Comment: @SteveJessop - intermediate sizes will do both. The "corners" will explode; the rest will collapse.

Comment: @TLW: is there a simple reason that every size must explode at the edges, or just the way the numbers come out? Unless you're assuming a disc must be thin, which is a fair assumption, it sounds like in effect you're saying that no cylinder is close enough to spherical, to pull its corners it. To which I say both boo and hiss, but it's a fair cop.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Think about a point on the rim at the extreme upper edge. Because of radial symmetry we know that the angle of pull will be through the center, and as such can disregard the third dimension. So we can treat it as a long thin rectangle, density increasing towards the center. Which can be broken up into a square and another rectangle. The square pulls at 45 degrees, the rest pulls , if anything, more radially. So the effective angle is >45 degrees. Which means you need at least sqrt(2) neutron star pressure. And an additional factor of ~1/0.58 due to the mean distance to the disk.